# Images on Oracle APEX page flickers with mouse movement on different objects

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am using Oracle APEX 5.0 on Oracle 11g R2. IE 11 is the front end browser. I see a very odd behavior most of the times (means not all the times).

Whenever I move the mouse on list boxes , or interactive report rows, or any other object on the page the static images starts flickering like mad.
As long as the mouse keeps moving they keep flickering. When the mouse is stopped they also stop.

These images are CSS background images in the header of the page (I modified the page template and added these images in the style attribute of the   tag of the template).

```
<header id="uHeader" style="background:url(#IMAGE_PREFIX#****.png) no-repeat right top">
```

But other images on the page itself added by the  tag also behave the same. Strange thing is that the CSS background images in the TABS (added via JQuery inline in the page) never showed this behavior at all.

```
$("nav ul li").each(function(){  
   if($(this).text().indexOf('**********')!=-1){  
       $(this).children('a').css(  
           {"background":'url(#IMAGE_PREFIX#*********.png) no-repeat 3px 5px', "padding-left":"31px" , "background-color":"#FFFFFF"}  
       );  
   };  
};
```

These images never flicker.

I have tested the pages in chrome and no flickering for any image on the page happens there at all.

Has anyone ever seen/encountered anything like this? or got it around by any means?

Regards,